# Error opening .apk in device, after making ionic build

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

After you create an apk with ionic build command does well, but get this message in red

: compileDebugJavaNote: C: \ Users \ alman \ ionic \ test \ platforms \ android \ src \ org \ ap
ache \ Cordova \ splashscreen \ SplashScreen.java use or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Rebuild With -Xlint: deprecation for details.

after trying to open the apk generate the device and I get error opening the file.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Acorrding to the error information,you have used the deprecated API.You can try this:

1.Rebuild With `-Xlint: deprecation`.

2.Find the deprecated API you used and replace it with the suitable API.[Preferred]

> *Note:Try to use the suitable API instead of deprecated API.Deprecated API is time bomb,sometime it's very dangerous.If you have developed
>   iOS app,you will understand it more.*

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough rept to comment it. so could you please Post the Error while you are opening your **.apk** file in your device.

If it is `Application Error: There was network Error(http://10.2.xxxx)` .So you need to add a **cordova whitelist plugin** please add below is the ionic command,

`ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git` .

Comment: The only message that appears is error can't open file, as do to see details of the error while trying to open the .apk on the device?